# Reduction from Circuit-Sat to 3-Sat

Tags: combinatorics, logic, computational-complexity, satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form

I'm reading the following notes on reduction from circuit-sat to 3-sat
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect1108.pdf

On the third page i'm unsure how they arrived at the following

In particular we just replace each statement of the form

$y_{3}=\mathrm{NAND}(y_{1},y_{2})$ as

$(y_{1} \cup y_{2} \cup y_{3})\cap(y_{1} \cup y_{2}' \cup y_{3})\cap(y_{1}' \cup y_{2} \cup y_{3}) \cap (y_{1}' \cap y_{2}' \cap y_{3}')$

I'm quite new to propositional logic, i've read a little bit about how to convert things to CNF so i thougt we should have $y_{3}=(y_{1}' \cup y_{2}')$. I'd appreciate any help on the reasoning behind how they replace the statement.

Comment: Note that you're not just converting $\text{NAND}(y_1,y_2)$ to CNF, which is indeed $y_1' \cup y_2'$, but the whole statement $y_3 \iff \text{NAND}(y_1, y_2)$.

Comment: The [Tseitin Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin_transformation) is commonly used to transform `Circuit SAT` to `CNF SAT`. The idea is to introduce one switching variable per gate. If all gates are restricted to two inputs, the transformation creates `3-SAT CNF` clauses with three or fewer literals.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about it is to just write down the truth table for both expressions and verify that they are equal (noting that in the first NAND expression, $y_3$ must be equal to the value of NAND$(y_1,y_2)$ or else the statement is false). There are only 8 possible ways to assign 3 variables, you just need to verify in each case that the values of the two Boolean expressions are equal.

Comment: Ok so essentially we are only allowing the statement to equal 1 when $y_{3}=\mathrm{NAND}(y_{1},y_{2})$ is satisfied. So my next question is how exactly is this connected to the overall output equalling 1?